# Value of a specific q-series / infinite product?

Tags: analysis, infinite-product

While working on a different problem, I've run into the infinite product:
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-2^{-i}) $$
Which I'm reasonably sure should be equal to $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. EDIT: It definitely doesn't equal this value, nevermind

However, I don't really have any notion of how to work with / prove things about an infinite product of this form. I tried considering the log of the partial products, but that doesn't seem to make the numerical value any easier to evaluate.

Doing some googling, these sorts of products seem to be called Euler products, or q series (see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html). However, I can't find much or anything online about methods for finding their value. Is there any process that would yield a precise answer in this case?

Comment: actually a bit smaller than 0.2888, where your prediction is 0.29289...

Comment: So given the answers on that question, does that imply we have no way to determine an exact value?

Comment: Yes, there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions known for this.

Comment: Also, $\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ cannot be equal to $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ because it is clearly trascendental (it is enough to consider the structure of its binary representation...)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you give one or two sentences more on that? Not sure I follow yet.